# "RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:1 and cuda:0!" When using custom module in Pytorch

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pytorch, conv-neural-network

apologies first for any improper layout as I am new to stack overflow. My issue is as follows:

I am currently creating a custom module inside an existing CNN using pytorch. I am doing this as part of my schools research, and so I have access to a super computer with multiple GPU devices. When I train my model, after running through the first validation set I run into the following error:

"RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:1 and cuda:0! (when checking argument for argument weight in method wrapper__cudnn_convolution)"

Now, every similar issue I see is when people are mixing tensors between the cpu and gpu, however mine seems to be strictly an issue with different cuda devices. For some context, when the model is initially loaded it is wrapped with nn.DataParallel. When I run the training excluding my custom module, the training works fine with multiple gpus. When I do implement the custom module and use just the cpu or just one cuda device, the training goes fine (albeit very slow) until the devices run out of memory from the amount of parameters I have to train.

Here is the code for my custom module:

```
class DivisiveNormBlock(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, channel_num = 512, size = 56, ksize = 4):
    super().__init__()
    self.channel_num = channel_num
    self.size = size
    self.ksize = ksize

    scale = 90 
    self.theta = torch.nn.Parameter(scale * torch.abs(torch.randn(self.channel_num, self.channel_num, device="cuda",
                                                                  requires_grad=True)))  # 512 thetas for a channel, 512 channels, same goes for...
    self.p = torch.nn.Parameter(
        scale * torch.abs(torch.randn(self.channel_num, self.channel_num, device="cuda", requires_grad=True)))
    self.sig = torch.nn.Parameter(
        scale * torch.abs(torch.randn(self.channel_num, self.channel_num, device="cuda", requires_grad=True)))
    self.a = torch.nn.Parameter(
        scale * torch.abs(torch.randn(self.channel_num, self.channel_num, device="cuda", requires_grad=True)))
    self.nI = torch.nn.Parameter(
        torch.abs(torch.randn(self.channel_num, self.channel_num, device="cuda", requires_grad=True)))
    self.nU = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.abs(torch.randn(self.channel_num, device="cuda", requires_grad=True)))
    self.bias = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.abs(torch.randn(self.channel_num, device="cuda", requires_grad=True)))
    self.gaussian_bank = torch.zeros(self.channel_num, self.channel_num, self.ksize * 2+ 1, self.ksize * 2+ 1,
                                     device="cuda")
    self.x = torch.linspace(-self.ksize, self.ksize, self.ksize * 2 + 1, device="cuda")
    self.y = torch.linspace(-self.ksize, self.ksize, self.ksize * 2 + 1, device="cuda")
    self.xv, self.yv = torch.meshgrid(self.x, self.y)

    for i in range(self.channel_num):
        for u in range(self.channel_num):
            self.gaussian_bank[i, u, :, :] = self.get_gaussian(i, u)

def get_gaussian(self, cc, oc):  #
    xrot = self.xv * torch.cos(self.theta[cc, oc]) + self.yv * torch.sin(self.theta[cc, oc])
    yrot = -self.xv * torch.sin(self.theta[cc, oc]) + self.yv * torch.cos(self.theta[cc, oc])
    g_kernel = (self.a[cc, oc] / \
                (2 * torch.pi * self.p[cc, oc] * self.sig[cc, oc])) * \
               torch.exp(-0.5 * ((((xrot) ** 2) / self.p[cc, oc] ** 2) + ((yrot) ** 2) / self.sig[cc, oc] ** 2))

    return g_kernel

def forward(self, x):

    x_test = self.dn_f(x)

    return x_test

def dn_f(self, x):

    batch_size = x.shape[0]
    under_sum = torch.zeros((self.channel_num, self.size, self.size), device="cuda")
    normalized_channels = torch.zeros((batch_size, self.channel_num, self.size, self.size), device="cuda")
    for b in tqdm(range(batch_size)):
        for i in range(self.channel_num):
            for u in range(self.channel_num):
                under_sum[u] = self.conv_gauss(torch.pow(x[b, i], self.nI[i, u]), self.gaussian_bank[i, u])
            normalized_channels[b, i] = torch.pow(x[b, i], self.nU[i]) / (
                    torch.pow(self.bias[i], self.nU[i]) + torch.sum(under_sum, 0))
    return normalized_channels

def conv_gauss(self, x_conv, gauss_conv):

    x_conv = torch.reshape(x_conv, (1, 1, self.size, self.size))
    gauss_conv = torch.reshape(gauss_conv, (1, 1, self.ksize * 2+ 1, self.ksize * 2+ 1))
    p = int((self.ksize*2)/2)
    output = F.conv2d(x_conv, gauss_conv, padding=p, stride=1)
    output = torch.reshape(output, (self.size, self.size))
    return output
```

And here is the full error traceback, the main error in question at the bottom:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train.py", line 390, in <module>
fire.Fire(command=FIRE_FLAGS)
File "/home/andrewc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 141, in Fire
component_trace = _Fire(component, args, parsed_flag_args, context, name)
File "/home/andrewc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 466, in _Fire
component, remaining_args = _CallAndUpdateTrace(
File "/home/andrewc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 681, in 
_CallAndUpdateTrace
component = fn(*varargs, **kwargs)
File "train.py", line 220, in train
results[validator.name] = validator()
File "train.py", line 366, in __call__
output = self.model(inp)
File "/home/andrewc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, 
in _call_impl
return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
File "/home/andrewc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", 
line 168, in forward
outputs = self.parallel_apply(replicas, inputs, kwargs)
File "/home/andrewc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", 
line 178, in parallel_apply
return parallel_apply(replicas, inputs, kwargs, self.device_ids[:len(replicas)])
File "/home/andrewc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/parallel_apply.py", 
line 86, in parallel_apply
output.reraise()
File "/home/andrewc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 434, in reraise
raise exception
RuntimeError: Caught RuntimeError in replica 1 on device 1.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/andrewc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/parallel_apply.py", 
line 61, in _worker
output = module(*input, **kwargs)
File "/home/andrewc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, 
in _call_impl
return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
File "/home/andrewc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 
141, in forward
input = module(input)
File "/home/andrewc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, 
in _call_impl
return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
File "/home/andrewc/Surround-Suppresion-for-VOneNet/modules.py", line 177, in forward
x_test = self.dn_f(x)
File "/home/andrewc/Surround-Suppresion-for-VOneNet/modules.py", line 190, in dn_f
under_sum[u] = self.conv_gauss(torch.pow(x[b, i], self.nI[i, u]), self.gaussian_bank[i, u])
File "/home/andrewc/Surround-Suppresion-for-VOneNet/modules.py", line 200, in conv_gauss
output = F.conv2d(x_conv, gauss_conv, padding=p, stride=1)
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, 
cuda:1 and cuda:0! (when checking argument for argument weight in method 
wrapper__cudnn_convolution)
```

It seems like it may have to do with the convolution at the bottom of the module? Any help on how to get this to work with multiple gpus is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I had a similar problem when restoring from checkpoint. The issue was that i loaded the the config saved from process 0 and also applied it to process 1. It also contained a `gpu` variable containing the cuda device number. It was only used for initializing DDP. I got this exception during the first forward pass. To debug this i inserted `if is_main_process(): import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` before the forward pass and at the beginning of the models forward method method and then issued `x.device` where x is the model input (image in my case). This might help you to find your problem too.